# Extract data from website as separate fields

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use excel to scrap some information from a website.

This is what shows on source:

```
<tr class="even">
    <td align="right">1</td>
    <td><a href="/kld/en/1.html">Acrobatic Maneuver</a></td>
    <td>Instant</td>
    <td>2W</td>
    <td>Common</td>
    <td>Winona Nelson</td>
    <td><img src="http://magiccards.info/images/en.gif" alt="English" width="16" height="11" class="flag2"> Kaladesh</td>
  </tr>
```

So I want to get everything that has even, and extract the data between the `<td></td>`

However, all I've found until now is this code

```
Sub getcards()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate "http://magiccards.info/query?q=%2B%2Be%3Akld/en&v=list&s=issue"

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    On Error GoTo abort
    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."
    Dim dd As String
    Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("even")
    For i = 0 To objCollection.Length

    dd = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("even")(i).innerText

    MsgBox dd
    Next i
abort:
    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Quit

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

It works in such a way that it extracts the data, but the output is `1Acrobatic ManeuverInstant2WCommonWinona Nelson Kaladesh` all together.

How can I do so it understands each `<td>` as a separate field, so I can extract it easily?

Comment: `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("even")(i).getElementsByTagName("TD")(x)`  you'd need a loop through the collection where x is the item.

Comment: Tried using `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("even")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(1)` but all it returned was `[object HTMLTableDataCellElement]`

Comment: so add the .innerText then :)

Comment: Maybe I'm a little dumb haha. Thanks

Comment: No probs.  Look at using the Internet controls and HTML Libraries also, and using a HTML Collection, specific for this purpose.  It will then give you intellisense, and the availability to view objects in locals window in the VBA IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're looping through `i` within `objCollection` you're actually looping through all elements with the `ClassName` of "even" as opposed to the elements inside the specific element you want.

Try this:

```
For i = 0 To objCollection.Length - 1
    For c = 0 to IE.document.getElementsByClassName("even")(i).getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1
        dd = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("even")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(c).innerText
        MsgBox dd
    Next c
Next i
```

Comment: It crashed when it tried to grab the last value, so I added a `-1` at the end of `for c = 0...` to it and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that would be because the `Length` function counts the elements but we're looping through indexes so it would always be one less - I'll add this in to the answer to help others.